# How to use sendKeys with iframes in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is the code I am using to send keys to a field in an iframe. I am using chrome driver. I dont see any error in the code on Eclipse console but the keys are also not sent to the fields. How do I send keys to the name fields?

```
Login.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement iframe=Login.driver.findElement(By.id("manageTabIframe"));
Login.driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
System.out.println("inside i frame");

try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

WebElement firstName= Login.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstName']"));
System.out.println(firstName);
firstName.clear();
firstName.sendKeys("Test");
Login.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `firstName.sendKeys("Test");`, and run in debug mode, does the `firstName.clear(); ` set the element out of focus? (similarly to clicking outside of the element)

Comment: Yes, after execution of firstName.clear(); or directly using firstName.sendKeys("Test"); i see the element is on focus.But the keys are not sent and no error on console as well.

Comment: I found that the issue is on chrome browser and the issue is not occurring on Mozilla Firefox.Chrome version is Version 65.0.3325.181 and Chrome driver version is 2.3.

Comment: You should upgrade chromedriver to latest 2.37. That is the version that supports chrome 64 to 66.

Comment: Yes the chromedriver version is 2.37.Sorry for the typo.